# Google map widget custom data

Tags: grails, maps

in Google Documents on some spreadsheets you have that world map widget/plugin that you can give country codes and frequencies and it'll generate a heatmap of the world with that data?

Can anyone suggest something similar to use in Grails? Obviously googling "Google Map" gives a million and one things about the actual Google Maps API, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it from a friend- it's referred to as a 'Geochart',

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart